# Str to numpy nd array

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame with three columns that contains both strings and numpy ndarray (images).
It's like this :

```
/some/strings/
[[[ 127. 123. 34,..
np.ndarray
np.ndarray
string
...
```

when I do pd.read_csv it stores everything as string. How can I transform the string to a numpy ndarray? 
I tried:

```
im1 = pd.Series(df.iloc[0,0]).to_numpy(dtype ='float32')
```

Error:

```
could not convert string to float: '[[[[153. 150. 135.]\n   [151. 148. 133.]\n   [151. 148. 133.]\n   ...\n   [ 51.  47.  38.]\n   [ 38.  34.  25.]\n   [ 43.  39.  30.]]\n\n  [[153. 150. 135.]\n   [151. 148. 133.]\n   [152. 149. 134.]\n ....
```

```
i1,i2,s = np.genfromtxt('df.csv', delimiter=',', unpack=True, usecols=[0,1,2])
```

Error:

```
(got 1 columns instead of 3)
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Why are you storing non homogeneous data in a column?

Comment: Because some images are created in the code and I cannot store them. At the same time I need created data and data already stored in my pc so I cannot create two different files.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. At all

Comment: I suspect you put image arrays in cells of the dataframe, and then saved it as a `csv`.  Look at the `csv` file.  Does one of the columns consist of quoted strings that look like string it couldn't convert to float?  That's the `str` display of a numpy array.  Recreating an array from such a string is difficult.  No, it's impossible, because the array is incomplete (the ellipsis '...\n ').  That `csv` file is garbage!

Comment: @hpaulj do you know a less stupid way to store a dataframe with ndarray? I tried with df.to_json but there are many ways to do that, I tried with the "records"  but is even worse..